# How to pass properties from object binding to a subview as a normal state variable

Tags: swiftui

I have a view with an object binding to a model. Now I want to extract a subview. When I define the same object binding on the subview everything works. But as the subview is a primitive view, I would like to only have a state variable instead of the full object binding.

Unfortunately, my subview doesn't update when the property of the model changes.

Some code (simplified):

```
private struct ControlButtons : View {
    @ObjectBinding var timerViewModel: TimerViewModel

    var body: some View {
        JumpBackButton(isDisabled: timerViewModel.isAtStart, jumpAction: { self.timerViewModel.jumpBack() })
    }
}

struct JumpBackButton: View {
    @State var isDisabled = false
    var jumpAction: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.jumpAction() }) {
            Image(systemName: "backward.end")
        }.buttonStyle(.plain).padding().disabled(isDisabled)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@State` are not designed to be passed any value. In fact, Apple recommends we declare them private, to avoid making such a mistake.

`@State` variables are meant to be used for a source of truth. If the value comes from the outside, it is not a source of truth then! I recommend you watch the WWDC2019 session: Data Flow with SwiftUI.

If your view needs data from outside, then it needs to point to it through a `@Binding`, `@ObjectBinding`, or `@EnvironmentObject`